# Which countries have openly supported the Russian invasion of Ukraine?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, international-relations

I know a number of (big) countries like China and India are ["fence sitting"](https://thediplomat.com/2022/03/can-modis-india-be-an-ally-of-the-west/) by neither condemning the attack nor endorsing. But besides Belarus, which I'm pretty sure endorsed with words too (besides their military cooperation), **which countries have voiced diplomatic support for Putin's invasion of Ukraine** (or "denazification" thereof if you want to use the Russian government's terms)?

N.B.: it was somewhat easier to find which countries [have recognized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_recognition_of_the_Donetsk_People%27s_Republic_and_the_Luhansk_People%27s_Republic#States_or_organizations_supporting_recognition_of_Donetsk_PR_and_Luhansk_PR_independence) the Donetsk and Luhansk People's Republics: Belarus, Syria, Venezuela, Kyrgyzstan, Nicaragua, Sudan, and the Central African Republic. I'm guessing the countries which unreservedly support the invasion of Ukraine is a subset of these.

Also there's a [video](https://news.sky.com/video/ukraine-invasion-belarusian-president-talks-over-map-of-ukraine-12555168) of Lukashenko giving a briefing over a map of Ukraine in which he is claiming (in somewhat rambling fashion--at least in translation) that Ukraine was planning to attack Belarus. (The video is intersting also because it gives some insight into the workings of the Lukashenko government. There's an army guy [probably a general], who instead of briefing Lukashenko on the military situation, simply stands at attention as Lukashenko "splains" to him the military "reality" as Lukashenko says it is.)

Comment: Does [Serbia](https://tass.com/world/1407763) [count](https://balkaninsight.com/2022/02/25/serbian-pro-regime-media-praise-russia-overrunning-ukraine/)?

Comment: @Thissitehasbecomeadump.: interesting, but it seem the support is from the pro-Russian press in that country. So it may be somewhat unofficial at this point.

Comment: We will presumably find out soon at the UN general assembly meeting.

Comment: @Allure: didn't that happen already yesterday and the day before that? Or is there some kind of vote planned for today? Ah, ok, [there is](https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2022/03/01/isolated-russia-defends-ukraine-war-at-un-general-assembly-a76669) a vote planned for today.

Comment: @Thissitehasbecomeadump. Serbia does not count. You can read [here](https://balkaninsight.com/2022/02/25/serbia-supports-ukraines-sovereignty-but-opposes-sanctions-on-russia-vucic-says/) everything about that.

Answer (score 5):

To partially answer my own question, at the UN General Assembly [today](https://inews.co.uk/news/un-russia-vote-full-voting-breakdown-north-korea-syria-back-putin-ukraine-invasion-1494907):

> 141 nations voted in favour of a UN General Assembly motion condemning the invasion of Ukraine, while just five – Belarus, North Korea, Eritrea, Syria and Russia – opposed it. [...]
>
> The resolution “deplores in the strongest terms the aggression by the Russian Federation against Ukraine” and “demands” that Russia “unconditionally withdraw all of its military forces from the territory of Ukraine.

It would still be interesting to know where countries that apparently supported Russia to a more limited extent (e.g. on LPR/DPR recognition) stand in relation to the invasion. For example, the Venezuelan declaration (quoted in Wikipedia) was that:

> President Nicolás Maduro "reaffirmed all his support" for Russian President Putin "in defense of peace in Russia", stating "the territory of Lugansk and Donetsk assumed the functions of people's republics to defend themselves from a massacre that the fascist sectors that had seized power in Ukraine began to execute hunting men, hunting women, assaulting families, bombing, with heavy weapons and a conflict began".

So from that one could have easily inferred the Venezuelan government would have offered unreserved support for Russia's actions in Ukraine, but apparently they didn't.

Actually, I see Venezuela is in the "No vote recorded" category, so I do wonder if US sanctions prevented their representative from attending, or something like that. On the other hand, Maduro did [speak at the UN](https://www.passblue.com/2021/09/22/venezuelas-maduro-fires-up-unga-while-a-fight-for-afghan-womens-rights-has-big-name-backing/) back in September (well, by pre-recorded message), so I don't think they're being totally prevented from attending. They [did have](https://youtu.be/zTYElOiFndA?t=15) a "guy on the ground" who introduced the speech.

Comment: Venezuela couldn't vote because they owe the UN money, and they have no voting rights until the fees are paid. https://www.voanews.com/a/iran-venezuela-and-sudan-lose-un-voting-rights-with-5-more/6394205.html

Comment: Why did Eritrea vote against the resolution?

Comment: @graffe: not exactly on Washington's friends list https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71325/what-reasoning-did-eritrea-provide-for-its-vote-on-the-un-resolution-against-the ; https://www.voanews.com/a/us-treasury-department-imposes-sanctions-on-eritrean-military-ruling-party-officials-/6311294.html

Comment: "I do wonder if US sanctions prevented their representative from attending, or something like that": The US has a special category of transit visa to allow diplomats who would otherwise be _persona non grata_ to travel to the UN headquarters in New York, in order to fulfill its obligations under the headquarters agreement.  People admitted in this status are supposed to proceed immediately to the area within 25 miles of Columbus Circle and remain there until they leave the US.

Answer (score 3):

The question dates back to five months ago and the answers can be updated. In addition to the mentioned countries, Iran has also [supported](https://www.iranintl.com/en/202207247847) Russia's invasion. Iran's leader has recently [received](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/russia-ukraine-war-iran-vladimir-putin-khamenei-nato-us/) Putin in Tehran and agreed to support Russia by providing weapons, especially drones. The agreement got extensive media coverage in Iran.

Comment: Iran has not supported, in the UN general voting Iran was neutral. Iran never said it gives Russia drones, but the US media said, it doesn't mean this is true.

Comment: "Iran's leader has recently visited Putin in Tehran" Gues you meaned it the other way around, as Putin has visited Iran's leader in Tehran.

Answer (score 1):

If we tallking also about unrecognized countries, then South Ossetia suports Russia the most in this conflict. The country has even send some of their soldiers to suport Russia and Donbass republics in this conflict as can be read in [this russian article](https://en.topcor.ru/24690-dlja-uchastija-v-voennoj-specoperacii-po-osvobozhdeniju-donbassa-otpravilis-voennosluzhaschie-juzhnoj-osetii.html?ysclid=l74pku3ufq252169224). An other unrecognized country which suports Russia is Abkhazia. While there is no oficial information about Abkhazia sending their soldiers to suport Russia in Donbass it was together with South Ossetia one of the first countries who recognized the Donbass republics.